# Fix links pointing to future pages added via PdfMerger

Tags: c#, itext, itext7, html-to-pdf

I'm trying to merge a few PDFs where the first PDF have a bunch of links to the other PDFs that are merged in later.

I start out by converting HTML to PDF and then I merge some PDFs onto that.

The HTML PDF have simple ancher links like these

```html
<a href="#some-id">Click here</a>

<div id="some-id">...</div>
```

This works great if the destination id exists when the PDF is generated via `HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument`.

But this is the problem. The destination is being added later via `PdfMerger`.
I tried playing around with NamedDestinations as referenced by https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/named-destinations

```cs
public void AppendPdf(string key, Document sourceDocument, Stream pdfStream)
{
    var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
    var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
    pdfDocument.AddNamedDestination(key, pdfDocument.GetFirstPage().GetPdfObject());

    var merger = new PdfMerger(sourceDocument.GetPdfDocument());
    merger.Merge(pdfDocument, 1, pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages());

    var nameTree = sourceDocument.GetPdfDocument().GetCatalog().GetNameTree(PdfName.Dests);
    nameTree.SetModified();
}
```

But to no avail :(

I also tried inspecting the the links them self, but `GetAsArray` throws a null expection

```cs
var obj = sourceDocument.GetPdfDocument().GetFirstPage().GetPdfObject();
var annots = obj.GetAsArray(PdfName.Annots); // throws
```

Please help :)

## EDIT

This code snippet should make it easy to run

```cs
using var stream = new MemoryStream();
var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(stream);
var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
var key = "future-id";
var html = $@"
<a href=""#some-id"">This link works!</a>
<a href=""#{key}"">Click here to go the first page of the merged PDF, but it does not work</a>

<div id=""some-id"" style=""page-break-before: always;"">Hello PDF</div>
";
var sourceDocument = HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(html, pdfDocument, new ConverterProperties());

using var pdfStream = File.OpenRead("path/to/pdf"); // change path to an actual pdf
AppendPdf(key, sourceDocument, pdfStream);

sourceDocument.Close();
var pdfBytes = stream.ToArray();
File.WriteAllBytes("path/to/result.pdf", pdfBytes); // change to desired path
```

Nuget packages

```
<PackageReference Include="itext7" Version="7.1.12" />
<PackageReference Include="itext7.pdfhtml" Version="3.0.1" />
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide more details on how to reproduce the issue? Which parameters do we need to pass to `AppendPdf`? What example PDF can be used to reproduce the issue etc. I guess people who would potentially reply here are looking for a way to copy the code, paste it in the IDE and run to reproduce and play around and right now it's quite tricky :)

Comment: @AlexeySubach good idea, I added a snippet

Comment: Hey, I tried to run your code but the missing piece is the example document that you are reading from location `"path/to/pdf"`

Comment: You need to change that to point to a PDF file. Also the output path must be changed. I put comments so it should be clear now. I also fixed the incorrect @string, it not runs :)

Comment: I know, but the actual PDF is missing. Which PDF do I use? Does the problem reproduce for every PDF? If not, then without the example PDF it will be hard to reproduce

Comment: any PDF will work, I think. It's not the merging of the PDFs that is the problem. It's the #future-id link to the first page of the merged PDF that's the issue

Answer (score 1):

Adding the named destination does not work in the following three lines of code because you opened the document in read-only mode (with `PdfReader`):

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
pdfDocument.AddNamedDestination(key, pdfDocument.GetFirstPage().GetPdfObject());
```

Instead, you should get the total number of pages in the source document you merge into, and that number + 1 would be the index of the first page of the document you merge into the source document and thus the page number in the output document to jump to:

```
int sourceDocumentPageCount = sourceDocument.GetPdfDocument().GetNumberOfPages();
```

Next to that, adding a destination is a bit trickier because you need to create a description of how you want to jump to your page (which location etc). It can be done in the following way:

```
PdfPage firstPageOfMergedDocument = sourceDocument.GetPdfDocument().GetPage(sourceDocumentPageCount + 1);
sourceDocument.GetPdfDocument().AddNamedDestination(key, PdfExplicitDestination.CreateFit(firstPageOfMergedDocument).GetPdfObject());
```

Full `AppendPdf` code that produced the correct result for me:

```
public static void AppendPdf(string key, Document sourceDocument, Stream pdfStream)
{
    var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
    var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);

    var merger = new PdfMerger(sourceDocument.GetPdfDocument());
    
    int sourceDocumentPageCount = sourceDocument.GetPdfDocument().GetNumberOfPages();
    
    merger.Merge(pdfDocument, 1, pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages());

    PdfPage firstPageOfMergedDocument = sourceDocument.GetPdfDocument().GetPage(sourceDocumentPageCount + 1);
    sourceDocument.GetPdfDocument().AddNamedDestination(key, PdfExplicitDestination.CreateFit(firstPageOfMergedDocument).GetPdfObject());
}
```